# Linux KVM .img converting to Hyper-V .vhd

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, hyper-v, kvm

I have a Linux server with KVM virtualitation, and a new Windows Server with Hyper-V virtualization.

I would like migrate my KVM images to the Windows Hyper-V...

How can is converting kvm image to hyper-v vhd?

Comment: This should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with with qemu-img:

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O vpc something.img something.vhd
```

or

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vpc something.img something.vhd
```

[Read this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Image_types) to get more info about supported virtual disk images formats.

Comment: Please looking my newer post.

Comment: This tools is good https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/

Answer (score 1):

There are inaccuracy in the question and in the answer.
VHD is a image format for VirtualPC. There is VHDX format for Hyper-V.
For migration to Hyper-V a right command will be for example:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 something.img -O vhdx something.vhdx
```

Comment: There is no inaccuracy. VHD is a valid Hyper-V disk format for any version of Hyper-V prior to Windows Server 2012, when the format was extended to include new features and the new version named VHDX. VHD is also a common shorthand for any Hyper-V disk file whether VHD or VHDX. However, your input is valuable for adding the syntax for converting specifically to VHDX.